# How to loop through drop down menus in different columns and display outcomes in separate columns

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a code that loops through a dynamic drop down menu and prints the different selections in their own cell in a separate column. However, I want to adapt this code to work with multiple drop down menus. Currently, when the user selects options from an adjacent drop down menu, the value overwrites the previous selections. I am attempting to create a loop that places the selections from each drop down menu in their own column. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very new to VBA.

I have attempted to create an ActiveCell.Column function underneath the Target.Row if statement, but I receive an error that a variable is required.

```
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Row = 11 Then
 'The following commented line causes variable error'
 'For ActiveCell.Column = 1 To 8'
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
        Dim val As String
        val = ActiveCell.Value
        If j = 0 Then
            Cells(11, j + 9).Value = val
        End If
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            Dim txt As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim FullName As Variant
            txt = ActiveCell.Value
            FullName = Split(txt, ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
                Cells(i + 11, 9).Value = FullName(i)
            Next i
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
```

Comment: Please add a line in the above code that indicates which instruction causes the error.

Comment: It is the "For ActiveCell.Column = 1 To 8" line that causes the error. I also added a comment to the code.  @donPablo

Comment: ActiveCell.Column is read only [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.column).  Either change Activecell or use cells to refer the cell on desired column depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a range function to loop through the cells, and then the offset function to print the values into the cells that I wanted. Works great now!